# How to query list of ancestors using closure tables in Django?

Tags: django

I have following models (among others), I' trying to inplement tree structure using closure tables:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Part {}: {}, {}".format(self.id, self.name, self.quantity)

    def path(self):
        ancestors = Part.objects.filter(closures_d__descendant__id__exact=self.id)
        print(len(ancestors))
        return "{}".format(reduce(lambda a, b: a+" &gt; "+b, map(lambda x: x.name, ancestors), ""))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'parts'

class Closure(models.Model):

    ancestor = models.ForeignKey(Part, related_name='closures_a')
    descendant = models.ForeignKey(Part, related_name='closures_d')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'closures'
```

The problem is `path` function does not work as expected, the query that fetches
ancestors from database returns only one object (the part that called it).
I checked generated SQL queries, and it appears that closures are ignored (output from connection.queries):

```
[{'time': '0.001', 'sql': 'SELECT "parts"."id", "parts"."name", "parts"."quantity", "parts"."manufacturer_id" FROM "parts" WHERE "parts"."id" = 101 '}]
```

How to do the join properly? (I mean Python/Django way, I can do this in raw SQL)

The query should look like this (101 is example id, part exists in db and has few ancestors, query below returns correct results):

```
SELECT * from parts p JOIN closures c ON p.id=c.ancestor_id WHERE c.descendant_id=101
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it right, query for ancestors should say:

```
ancestors = Part.objects.filter(closures_a__descendant_id__exact=self.id)
```

instead of:

```
ancestors = Part.objects.filter(closures_d__descendant__id__exact=self.id)
```

Query returns correct results, but displayed SQL still looks wrong (no JOIN),
I have no idea why, I got generated query using this code (path function from class Part from question):

```
def path(self):
    ancestors = Part.objects.filter(closures_a__descendant_id__exact=self.id)
    from django.db import connection
    print(connection.queries)
    return "{}".format(reduce(lambda a, b: a+" &gt; "+b, map(lambda x: x.name, ancestors), ""))
```